# Is this sequence monotonically increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Define $(p_n)_n$ recursively by $p_0(x) = 0$ and $p_{n+1}(x) = p_n(x) + \frac{1}{2}(x - p_n(x)^2)$.  I'm pretty sure this sequence is monotonically increasing for $x \in [0,1]$, but I want to prove it.  I've tried using induction, but I get stuck:

> (Assume $p_k \leq p_{k+1}$)
>
> $p_{k+1} \leq p_{k+2}$
>
> $\Rightarrow p_{k+1} \leq p_{k+1}(x) + \frac{1}{2}(x - p_{k+1}(x)^2)$
>
> $\Rightarrow 0 \leq x - p_{k+1}(x)^2$ (??)

I'm trying to prove this as a part of this question: [Prove $p_n(x) \rightarrow \sqrt{x}$ uniformly as $n \rightarrow \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563679/prove-p-nx-rightarrow-sqrtx-uniformly-as-n-rightarrow-infty/1563741#1563741), but I added this part as an edit so nobody has commented on it.  If there is a better way to draw attention to the edited question, let me know.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean monotonically increasing or strictly increasing?

Comment: @Arjang: Monotonically increasing.  Sorry, I'll edit the question.

Comment: Is there a restriction on $x$?  It's not increasing for, say, $x=3$.

Comment: @lulu: $x \in [0,1]$.  I'm really not doing so hot, am I?  I'll edit again.

Comment: For your induction, could you show for example that $x \geq p_k(x)$ for all $k$ by induction?

Comment: @JamieB:  I don't think so.  The problem is, the sequence $(p_n)_n$ converges to $\sqrt{x}$, so the opposite of what you said is eventually true.

Comment: Oh yes, of course! I think I meant the square $p_n (x)^2 \leq x $; if you're  sequence is to be monotonically increasing, then we should have that. Then that should be possible to show by induction

Comment: @JamieB:  I hadn't thought of that.  I think that should work.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: Throughout, $0 \leq x \leq 1$. As Solitary showed (modulo rearrangement) in the answer to your other question,
$$
\sqrt{x} - p_{n + 1}(x)
  = \left(\sqrt{x} - p_n(x)\right)\left[1 - \tfrac{1}{2}(p_n(x) + \sqrt{x})\right],
\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
0 \leq 1 - \tfrac{1}{2}(p_k(x) + \sqrt{x})
  \leq 1 - \tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{x}
  \leq 1 \quad\text{for each $k \geq 0$.}
\tag{2}
$$
Since $0 \leq \sqrt{x} - p_{0}(x)$, (1) and (2) immediately imply $0 \leq \sqrt{x} - p_{n}(x)$ for all $n$, and
$$
\sqrt{x} - p_{n+1}(x) \leq \sqrt{x} - p_{n}(x),
$$
i.e., $p_{n}(x) \leq p_{n+1}(x)$.