# Show that a next polynomial function sequence converges uniformly to $\sqrt{x}$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that polynomial function sequence $(P_n)$ define recursively as $P_0(x)=0$ and $P_{n+1}(x)=P_n(x)+\frac{1}{2}(x-P_n^2(x))$ converges uniformly in $[0,1]$ to the function $f(x)=\sqrt x$.

I've tried to show that is a Cauchy's sequence but I've not got something. Because I don't know how to explain that $|P_n^2(x)-x|$ is a small quantity.

Comment: I don't know if this will be helpful, but I feel like you can show that it converges pointwise to something by showing it's monotone increasing and bounded above by $\sqrt{x}$.  Then if it converges to something, you can use the defining equation to show it must converge to $\sqrt{x}$.  I don't see how to show it converges uniformly.

Comment: See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563679/prove-p-nx-rightarrow-sqrtx-uniformly-as-n-rightarrow-infty?rq=1